# Jenkins deployment on multiple servers with different configurations

Tags: deployment, jenkins, server, configuration-files

We are using jenkins to build and deploy our project.
Currently we build the project (It's a Spring java application) in one jenkins job and deploy it on our servers in an other jenkins job. The result of the build job is a war file which gets build and deployed by maven to tomcat.

This worked really well till we came to the point that we needed different configuration files (spring applicationContext.xml) for the application depending on which server the application is deployed. The configuration file comes packed in the war file from the build job.

What would be a good way to modify the build process for two servers with two configuration files? Is there a way to avoid having two builds just because we need two different configuration files in the war files?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supply the configuration files, per environment, at the time of deployment.
It overwrites whatever is there as part of .war

Comment: My I humbly ask how you supply the configuration files at deployment time? Currently I opted to just split dynamic and static configuration and copy a static configuration file to a configured classpath into the local tomcat. 

In our case the tomcat is running and is redeployed with maven cargo.

Comment: I have my own deployment scripts (in bash, executed by Jenkins). When I trigger the deployment job from Jenkins, it checks out from SVN the environment-specific configuration (as provided by job parameters), and pushes that, along with the .war to the remote server. There, the deployment bash script unpacks the .war, and overwrites the supplied config files on top.

Comment: Ok, deployment by script and job parameters does the trick. Thx!